# fixing a php tokenizing pattern

Tags: php, regex, perl, tokenize, preg-split

i have a Perl script which tokenize a string

```
@s=split /([^a-zA-Z \t\-\'\,\.]+)/, $_[0];  # tokenized with separators
```

so if i have a string `$s="The large [[bear]] is dangerous."`

it will return `array("The large", " [[", "bear", "]] ", "is dangerous", ".")`

But the regex pattern doesn't seem to work when i used it on a php script.

```
$tokens = preg_split("/[^a-z \t\-\'\,\.]+/i", $s);
```

does anyone have any idea about the problem?

Comment: Perhaps because the pattern is different? Also, please be more specific about "doesn't work". What does or doesn't it do that it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to run ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/OOx4eb)):

```
$s="The large [[bear]] is dangerous.";
$pattern = '/([^a-zA-Z \t\-\\\'\,\.]+)/';    
$tokens = preg_split($pattern, $s, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);    
print_r($tokens);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => The large
    [1] => [[
    [2] => bear
    [3] => ]]
    [4] =>  is dangerous.
)
```

Details:

- The pattern must be properly expressed as a string in PHP, mind the string escape sequences. In a single quoted string `\'` is written as `\\\'`.
- You want to split including the delimiters, you need to use the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag.

See [Single quoted Strings<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) and [`preg_split`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

**Edit:** To split at the punctuation, just remove them from the pattern ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/fo70Yl)):

```
$pattern = '/([^a-zA-Z \t]+)/';
```

Comment: though it didn't split the dot(.), comma(,), and single quote(')

Comment: And whitespaces differ as well. If you want to split at the punctation, just remove them from the pattern, that does the job. - added another example, still not adding the whitespaces as in perl.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
\'
```

Is not correct when your string is delimited by double quotes. It will be an actual backslash followed by a quote character.

And these as well:

```
\-\'\,\.
```

Just write them direct without the backslash.